# Run an Azure CLI task as test for Azure Devops YAML pipeline

Tags: automated-tests, azure-pipelines

I want to add an AZ CLI tasks that runs as a test task in my pipeline.

I can always add an AZ CLI task with --query but I want this task to run just as a Test so that if the --query fails or AZ CLI command fails with some error code, I want it to be reported as failed test and it should not fail the pipeline.

Can this be achieved somehow?

---

UPDATE

If I run az cli command like

```sh
output=$(az acr repository show --name <ACR-name> --image <Image-name>:<Incorrect-version> --query "name" --output tsv

 echo $output
```

And since the version is incorrect the output would be "ERROR: Error: the specified tag does not exist. Correlation ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Is it possible to publish this as a Test result tab of YAML pipeline?

Comment: What are you testing? There are various tasks for the services in Azure that have testing in them. For Example .Net Has its own testing task.

Comment: Actually, I have created a pipeline that pushes an image to an ACR. The ACR's access policies does not allow any individual user show the images and tags available in the repository.
So, I have added an AZ CLI task to fetch the required tag.
But I want to publish the output of this task as a result in Test tab, No matter what the output is, Success / Fail.

Comment: @Jason: Something like if I run az cli command like 
output=$(az acr repository show --name <ACR-name>  --image <Image-name>:<Incorrect-version> --query "name" --output tsv)

echo $output

the output would be  ERROR: Error: the specified tag does not exist. Correlation ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

now can I publish this in the "Test tab"  of Azure Pipeline.

Maybe something like 
echo "##vso[task.publishTest]$output"